# Laravel Eloquent, Buscar elementos de una tabla verificando datos de otra tabla

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Estoy tratando de Seleccionar elementos de una tabla pero como condicional necesito verificar datos de otra tabla, en concreto una tabla es de **cruceros** y la otra es de **crucero_fechas** y necesito obtener todos los cruceros con fechas existentes mayores a hoy.

```
$cruceros_filter = Crucero::where('cruceros.activo', 1)
          ->whereNotNull('precio_minimo')
          ->conDestino($request->input('destino'))
          ->deNaviera($request->input('naviera'))
          ->enPuerto($request->input('puerto'))
          ->enMessalida($request->input('mes_salida'))
          ->deDuracion($request->input('duracion'))
          ->whereExists(
            function ($query) {
              $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                      ->from('crucero_fechas')
                      ->whereRaw('crucero_fechas.id_crucero = cruceros.id')
                      ->where('crucero_fechas.activo', 1)
                      ->whereDate('crucero_fechas.fecha', '>', date('Y-m-d'));
          })
          ->orderBy('prioridad','ASC')
          ->orderBy('subprioridad','ASC')
          ->distinct()
          ->get();
```

Primero ejecuto unos Scopes para el filtrado, luego estoy utilizando ->whereExists() para realizar este filtro que estoy comentando, he realizado varias pruebas y no me funciona.

¿Sabrían si lo puedo hacer de otra manera?